# The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: c#, xml, c#-2.0

I have code that is supposed to either add an [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the root element of a document, or replace an existing element if there is one. Here is my code:

```
if (existingInfo != null)
{
    existingInfo.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(existingInfo, newInfo);
}
else
{
    this.rootElement.AppendChild(info)
}
configDocument.Save(this.filePath);
```

If I am appending a new item this is not a problem. However when I try to add a new item I get an [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) stating "The node to be removed is not a child of this node"

This is a 2.0 application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated [in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.replacechild%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the first argument to `ReplaceChild` must be the new node, not the old one.

Therefore, try:

```
existingInfo.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newInfo, existingInfo);
```

Comment: It's always the little things. I can't test this right now but I'm marking it as the answer as I am confident this is my error.